# Shopify (Dawn) theme - Translations missing on the development version

Tags: triggers, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am developing our site (iqgame.ro) with the Dawn theme and have a running live version with data translated to 3 additional languages. The live site is okay and its data is displayed well.

But by running `shopify theme open` on our development git branch, data is displayed only in the default (Romanian) language and pushing any commits to the live branch deletes all the translations.
Any suggestions to solve this issue, please?

The *dev* version is many commits ahead the *live* site, but I cannot push my modifications because up-to-date & translated data (managed online, through the shopify account) would be discarded.

Comment: 1. Is your git dev branch in sync with a theme like so? 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMFfQ.png  
 2. Could you show/explain the translation files in both live & dev themes?  
3. If it's only for dev purposes why are you using the `shopify theme open` command instead of the `shopify theme dev` command?